# Serving flowplayer from cherokee webserver

Tags: cherokee, video-streaming, swf, video

When I download [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) locally on my machine and open index.html, the example video runs fine, no problems.

I have a linode running cherokee 1.2.2 with a basic 'List and Send' virtual server setup. If I simply download the [flowplayer zip](http://releases.flowplayer.org/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.zip), unzip it in my virtual server's root directory, then navigate to the example directory, I see the page fine but the flash video section is just black, with no video and no controls.

I'm not changing a single file in the flowplayer zip, just extracting it. Looking at my cherokee access log I can see that the swf file is being served fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like it had something to do with cherokee's mime type setting for `.swf` files.  I changed the mime type of `.swf` files from `application/x-shockwave-flash` to `application/octet-stream` and now it works.